# html things gets down when adding a div

Tags: html, css

Please check the image:

[image]

Check the black circle.

This black circle contains the chart that was locates in the Service Level Per Campaing, but when I added the red area, the charts drop down as you see.

can you help me please?

I want to keep the chart in its correct location and put this red area above it.

This is the code:

```
 <div style="width: 45%; float: left; margin-left:5%">
                    <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                        <h3>Service Level Per Campaign</h3>
                        <%-- Start Dropdown Code --%>
                        <a id="DropdownSeviceLink" href="#">+</a>
                        <div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server" >
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DropdownCheckbox.js"></script>
                        <%-- End Dropdown Code --%>
                    </div>
```

The red area is the div with id `campaignDiv` I fill it dynamically.

The css of campaignDiv is:

```
#DropdownSeviceLink {
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
a#DropdownServiceLink:visited {
    color:inherit;
}
#campaignDiv {
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
```

The whole code

http://jsfiddle.net/jdhMs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the red box has to be above then the most easy way to do this is to change the position:relative to absolute. (The parent div, chartHeaderClass, should have a position: relative).

```
#campaignDiv {
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 yes that works really. thanks will accept ur answer when the systems allows